How do "boulomai" and "thelema" compare with each other in Luke 22:42?
Luke 22:42  ESV

'saying, "Father, if you are willing, remove this cup from me. Nevertheless, not my will, but yours, be done."'

willing/boulei [from boulomai], verb, present, indicative, deponent.
will/thelema, noun, nominative.
What is the meaning  of 'boulei'[boulomai] in "if you are  willing", and why does this change to 'thelema' when Jesus refers to his own will?
Does comparing 'boulei' as a deponent verb with 'thelema' a noun, reveal any insights into the meaning of this verse?

In Luke 22:42, the distinction between "boulomai" and "thelema" adds nuance to Jesus’s prayer and His submission to the Father’s will. Let's explore this difference, especially in light of the examples from 1 Esdras 8:16, 2 Maccabees 1:3, and Psalm 39:9, where both terms appear together, revealing their complementary but distinct roles.
Boulomai (βούλομαι) as seen in "if you are willing" (boulei) is a verb, in the present indicative deponent form, that refers to a deliberate or intentional will—often a considered, determined choice or decision. Here, Jesus is asking the Father if He has "intended" or "resolved" to remove the cup (a metaphor for His suffering and impending crucifixion). This verb can imply an action aligned with the Father’s ultimate plan and divine wisdom, suggesting that Jesus seeks confirmation of the Father’s specific intention at that moment.
Thelema (θέλημα), on the other hand, is a noun in this context, representing “will” in a broader, sometimes less defined sense, encompassing God's desires or purposes. When Jesus says, "not my will, but yours," He uses "thelema" to refer to His personal inclination or desire, which He ultimately places under the Father's greater divine purpose. The contrast between "boulomai" and "thelema" thus captures Jesus’s submission, accepting not just a specific decision but aligning His entire disposition and desire with the Father’s ultimate purpose.
Intertextual Examples:
In 1 Esdras 8:16, "boulomai" indicates a resolved choice, while "thelema" signifies God’s broader will or purpose. This passage shows a harmonization of specific action (boulomai) with divine purpose (thelema), mirroring the distinction in Jesus's prayer.
2 Maccabees 1:3 illustrates a "willing soul" (psyche boulomenē) as one whose desires are deeply inclined toward fulfilling God’s “thelemata” (plural of thelema), suggesting alignment of personal inclination with God’s will.
In Psalm 39:9 (LXX 40:8), the speaker expresses a personal choice ("I have willed" or "I delight") to do God's "thelema," again underscoring the choice to conform to God’s overarching will.
In Luke 22:42, therefore, the contrast between "boulei" (if you have resolved this course of action) and "thelema" (the Father’s larger purpose) highlights that Jesus is not simply inquiring about an immediate choice, but acknowledging and submitting to the Father’s overarching divine will. The deponent nature of "boulomai" (appearing passive in form but active in meaning) also emphasizes that Jesus’s request respects the Father’s active decision-making. Ultimately, Jesus’s use of "thelema" expresses a surrender of His own desires, a profound yielding of His human inclination to the Father’s ultimate purpose.
This distinction gives deeper insight into the prayer's meaning: it reflects not only submission to a single decision but a full alignment with God’s divine, eternal plan.

The simple answer for Luke 22:42 is that βούλομαι is the verb "to will something to happen"; while θέλημα is the noun denoting a person's will or act of will.  Here is the more complicated answer from the BDAG lexicon -
βούλομαι (boulomai)

to desire to have or experience something, with implications of planning accordingly, wish, want, desire, eg, Acts 25:22, Philmn 13, 1 Tim 6:9, James 4:4
to plan on a course of action, intend, plan, will,


of humans: Matt 1:19, Mark 15:15, Acts 5:28, etc
of God, Jesus or Holy Spirit: Luke 22:42, James 1:18, Heb 6:17, 2 Peter 3:9, Matt 11;27, Luke 10:22, 1 Cor 12:11

θέλημα (theléma)

what one wishes to happen, objective sense, what is willed, eg, Rom 2:18, Matt 6:10, 26:42, Luke 11:2, John 6:39, Luke 22:42, Acts 21;14, Col 4:12, Heb 10:10, etc
the act of willing or desiring, subjective sense, will, eg, 2 Peter 1:21, 1 Cor 7:37, Luke 23:25, Eph 1:5, 11, 1 Peter 3:17, Rom 15:32, etc.

Jesus set the ultimate and perfect example to all Christians of submission to the Father's will and plan for His life.  This is reinforced in the prayer that Jesus taught His disciples to pray -

" ... Thy will be done ... " Matt 6:10, Luke 11:2

In commenting on Luke 22:42, Bengel offers this:

Luke 22:42. Εἰ βούλει παρενεγκεῖν, if thou he willing, remove The Infinitive put for the Imperative is a frequent usage of the Greeks.
See note on Revelation 10:9.[246] And in this passage, indeed, such an
Enallage (or change of mood and tense) expresses the reverential
modesty of Jesus towards the Father. But in this passage, if we
suppose an aposiopesis of the verb παρένεγκε [and make παρενεγκεῖν the
Infin. after βούλει, this feeling of reverential modesty will be still
more expressively conveyed.
The Infinitive expressing the absolute idea of the verb, irrespective
of the particular relations of mood and tense, tends to impart the
feeling of majesty to the language when used for the Imperative;
especially when God speaks. It was often used archaically for the
Imperative, and also for the Imperfect Indicative, in both Latin and
Greek.


thelēma
Looking at its etymology, the word thelēma (G2309) is based on the verb thelō (G2307), meaning to will, to wish, to desire, to intend, which is in turn based on the word haireō (G138), meaning to take, to choose, to prefer. Underlying thelēma is thus the basic concept of choice or preference.
bouloumai
The word bouloumai (G1014) is the middle form of a primary verb meaning “to will.” Bouloumai is the root of the words boulē (G1012), meaning counsel, purpose, will, plan, and boulēma (G1013), meaning counsel, purpose, will, plan. Though etymologically unrelated, both bouloumai and thelō can translate into English as “to will.” And while what they represent may appear similar, if we look beneath the surface, they are not the same. As I understand it, underlying thelō is the concept of choice; underlying bouloumai is that of purpose.
The OP asks, “What is the meaning of 'boulei' [boulomai] in ‘if you are willing' and why does this change to 'thelema' when Jesus refers to his own will?”
The use of bouloumai references what the Father wills from the perspective of his plans and purposes. The use of thelēma, on the other hand, references Jesus’ will from the perspective of his preference, which is for the cup and everything that it represents to be taken away. Jesus’ will at that moment is, I believe, a natural response to something so contrary to his nature.
The use of a noun instead of a verb allows for an important distinction, one between “my will” and “yours” as well as the subordination of the one to the other. The submission of Jesus’ will to that of the Father’s is, I believe, in itself an important act of will. It also confirms the truth of Jesus’ words in John 10:18 : “No one takes it from me, but I lay it down of my own accord.” Between the Father’s purpose and its completion, there lies of necessity Jesus’ acquiescence and submission. In my opinion, Lk 22:42 marks a pivotal moment in God’s plan of salvation and serves as an example that each of us through Christ are meant to follow.

I found all the answers to this question to be valuable. Thank you to all three submitters. I deeply appreciate your insight.
I came to this same question when comparing Revelation 4:11 and Ezekiel 33:11.
Thou art worthy, O Lord, to receive glory and honor and power: for thou hast created all things, and for thy pleasure they are and were created. (Rev 4:11)
Say unto them, As I live, saith the Lord GOD, I have no pleasure in the death of the wicked; but that the wicked turn from his way and live: turn ye, turn ye from your evil ways; for why will ye die, O house of Israel? (Ez 33:11)
The Greek word translated "pleasure" in Revelation 4:11 is "thelēma". This tells me that all things were created according to God's will for God's pleasure. He desired, wanted, and was pleased to create all things, including all people.
Ezekiel is written in Hebrew, however the Greek Septuagint translates אֶחְפֹּץ֙ "pleasure" in Ezekiel 33:11 as "bouloumai". This means that God did NOT plan or predetermine the death of the wicked, as some propose. Even in English this makes sense in context, for if that misinterpretation were true, then why would God implore the wicked to repent when they could not do so? He wouldn't. And this proper interpretation of Ezekiel 33:11 perfectly dovetails with Revelation 4:11 and the rest of Scriptures. To God all glory and honor and power. Amen.

Good observation. The LXX interprets this as you said, which helps us to see God's heart. https://biblehub.com/greek/1014.htm  "But I will judge each of you according to your own ways." (Ezekiel 33:20b)
